# navigating from one website page to an other website page

Tags: asp.net

i want to carry a message from asp.net application to another social networking website through href html element and i need to display that message when i loggs into that website(into To textBox).

Please provide the answer .

Comment: Do need to display the message in a textbox of the `another social networking` site? In that case, you have to modify source code of that  `another social networking` site

Answer (score 1):

You could add the data directly to the url like:

http://new.site/?data=data

or if the two sites can share a database you can insert that data into the database assigned with a hash, and you only pass the hash to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (I'm almost sure I don't), it sounds like you can use a querystring value.

Your href attribute in an anchor tag would be like:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/?message=My New message">Link</a>
```

"message" could also be a numerical value or another identifier that both the application and the website share information about.

The destination site reads the message value from the querystring, performs any necessary lookup, and presents the result message to the user.